# Powershell Scope - variable becomes blank

Tags: powershell

I am trying to understand scope in Powershell.  A simplified extract from my code is:

```
$AppData = (Get-Item env:appdata).value
$userName = $env:username
# The following 5 lines will query AD and get an ADUser object with all information
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$userName))"
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$searcher.Filter = $filter
$ADUserPath = $searcher.FindOne()
$ADUser = $ADUserPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
write-host $ADUser.mobile
$usercell = $ADUser.mobile
write-host $usercell

If ($usercell = ""){
write-host "In if code "
write-host $usercell      
}
else{
write-host "In else code "
write-host $usercell}
```

The output is:-

```
+64 21 999 150
+64 21 999 150
In else code
```

This tells me that the code is successfully extracting the extended attribute mobile from ADU, and is successfully copying it to the variable $usercell.
It also tells me that the value of $usercell is correctly read by the code; it enters the "else" code.
So why does that "else" code not know the value of $usercell?

Answer (score 3):

`$usercell = ""` is an assignment, you probably meant `$usercell -eq ""`

Here is a relevant excerpt from the output of `get-help about_Comparison_Operators`:

```
Windows PowerShell includes the following comparison operators:

      -eq
      -ne
      -gt
      -ge
      -lt
      -le
      -Like
      -NotLike
      -Match
      -NotMatch
      -Contains
      -NotContains
      -In
      -NotIn
      -Replace

  -eq
      Description: Equal to. Includes an identical value.
      Example:

        PS C:\> "abc" -eq "abc"
        True
```

Comment: That obvious!  Thank you.

Comment: @OrmondStock, glad I could help! Please feel free to press the green check mark, if it answers your question.